# Convert fixed size array to variable sized array in Go

Tags: arrays, go, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a fixed size array `[32]byte` to variable sized array (slice) `[]byte`:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        var a [32]byte
        b := []byte(a)
        fmt.Println(" %x", b)
}
```

but the compiler throws the error:

```
./test.go:9: cannot convert a (type [32]byte) to type []byte
```

How should I convert it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `b := a[:]` to get the slice over the array you have. Also see [this](http://blog.golang.org/slices) blog post for more information about arrays and slices.

Answer (score 19):

There are no variable-sized arrays in Go, only slices. If you want to get a slice of the whole array, do this:

```
b := a[:] // Same as b := a[0:len(a)]
```

Comment: Note that slices behave a bit like variable-sized arrays in that, if you keep using `append` on a slice, it will grow by reallocation when necessary.